# Hint needed for practical use of interfaces

Tags: go, interface

I wanted to be 'clever' but for the moment I'm stuck :D

I have slices of different types and wrote a function to eliminate duplicates in these slices.

I created an interface which defines a function to return an identifier.

My function to eliminate duplicates is implemented against that interface.

But when trying to compile I get an error where I'm not totally sure how to solve this.

```
package main

type IDEntity interface {
    EntityID() int64
}

type Foobar struct {
    ID int64
}

func (s *Foobar) EntityID() int64 {
    return s.ID
}

func EliminateDuplicatesInSlice(sliceIn []*IDEntity) []*IDEntity {
    m := map[int64]bool{}

    for _, v := range sliceIn {
        if _, seen := m[v.EntityID()]; !seen {
            sliceIn[len(m)] = v
            m[v.EntityID()] = true
        }
    }
    // re-slice s to the number of unique values
    sliceIn = sliceIn[:len(m)]

    return sliceIn
}

func main() {
    foo1 := &Foobar{
        ID: 1,
    }

    foo2 := &Foobar{
        ID: 2,
    }

    foo3 := &Foobar{
        ID: 3,
    }

    testSlice := []*Foobar{foo1, foo2, foo2, foo3}

    EliminateDuplicatesInSlice(testSlice)
}
```

Output is:

```
go run test.go
# command-line-arguments
./test.go:19: v.EntityID undefined (type *IDEntity is pointer to interface, not interface)
./test.go:21: v.EntityID undefined (type *IDEntity is pointer to interface, not interface)
./test.go:45: cannot use testSlice (type []*Foobar) as type []*IDEntity in argument to EliminateDuplicatesInSlice
```

I'm most confused about `(type *IDEntity is pointer to interface, not interface)`.

Can someone please clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike struct, having a pointer to an interface is useless. Your interface must declare `EntityID() int64`, so if you have a variable `a` of type `IDEntity`, then you can do `a.EntityID()`. However, if you have a pointer to an interface, then you can't call its methods.

This is about the type of the receiver for your methods. In your example, `*Foo` implements `IDEntity`, but `Foo` doesn't. So, `*Foo` is an `IDEntity`, but `Foo` isn't.

About your code, you have two lines to fix:

- Change the prototype of `EliminateDuplicateInSlice` to `func EliminateDuplicatesInSlice(sliceIn []IDEntity) []IDEntity`
- Change the type of the slice you pass to this function from `[]*Foo` to `[]IDEntity`

Comment: I have to define `IDEntity` on `Foo` and not `*Foo` because I'm wrapping an interface around it and I can't have/use a pointer to an interface even if I add `&Foo{}` to my list?
Also: I must manually convert my `[]*Foo` to `[]IDEntity` before calling `EliminateDuplicatesInSlice `?

Comment: No, `IDEntity` is defined on `*Foo` and that's alright. `*Foo` is an `IDEntity`. `Foo` is nothing. `**Foo` is an `*IDEntity` (don't use it). Just apply the modifications and play with your code to understand how structs and interfaces are related exactly, it will be far more effective than anything I can say.